# Check if user is changing only his data

Tags: node.js

I am building an API with two types of users; admin and guest. I've created a middleware which checks if user is allowed to access certain API endpoint and I set it like this:

```
app.all('/api/*', [require('./validateReq')]);
```

All my routes look like this:

```
/api/*
/api/admin/*
```

`validateReq` checks if token is passed and is it valid. If it's valid, request is normally processed.

My User model has a boolean value `admin` which in combination with token verifies additional `/api/admin` routes.

My question now is how can I make sure that user is modifying only his data. One example is if he is updating his profile. What can prevent another user to modify profile of some other user? My protection works only that it allows logged in users to access `/api` routes and admin users to access `/api/admin` routes.

I need something like "currentUser" field which I can access from anywhere and check it in all my routes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Each of your users need id.
2. When you Authenticate user you check if his id is correct.
3. When user try to modify anyone data, you have to check which this data is. This checks are in routes. (For example, profile of each user has this user id, and on update you add condition 'profileUserId === authenticateUserId')

How to get userId in authentication process?
If you are not sure how implement it you should read about it because it is important security functionality, For example in http://passportjs.org/docs (this is super module for this jobs). 
In short, If you authenticate by session, you store id in session.

Answer (score 0):

One option is expose a set of routes that don't accept the user's id.

Example:
Instead of /profile/{id}, expose /myprofile.

Then get the user's id from the token/cookie and make the appropriate db/api call. If you need both routes for different roles, that is the responsibility of your middleware.

Also, there is a middleware library called [Connect-AccessControl](https://github.com/futurechan/Connect-AccessControl) that probably already meets your use cases regarding restful access-control (shameless plug).